# So what exactly does “from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL” do?

Tags: python, operators

I understand it's an inside joke that's meant to stay (just like “`from __future__ import braces`”), but what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It's related to [PEP 0401: BDFL Retirement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/)

Barry refers to Barry Warsaw, a well-known Python developer. The `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` basically replaces the `!=` operator with `<>`.

Comment: More importantly, it enables `<>` syntax in Python 3.

Comment: The link says the `print` statement is back too.

Comment: Huh. When I try to run this import against Python 3.3, it crashes with a `SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`. Perhaps this functionality hasn't been maintained. :P

Comment: btw -- unlike braces, it's in `.all_feature_names` so if you decide to run a program (say a doctest) with all future features enabled (having looked through the list and seen that they're all what you want), it can definitely bite you.

Comment: As S. Lott said, it enables `<>` syntax in Python 3, but it also *disables* the `!=` operator.  (So as far as I know, you can't have both.)

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned above, barry is Barry Warsaw, a well known Core Python Dev
However, the FLUFL has not been explained

It stands for "Friendly Language Uncle For Life" an inside joke among the other python core devs at the time. The reason this enables the `<>` syntax, is that he was the primary person who wanted to use the `<>` operator

Answer (score 19):

The April Fool's joke [PEP 0401](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/) is really funny and so its current implementation.
It works very good interactively from the terminal or by `python3 -i` from the standart input, but surprisingly not from a normal script or without `-i`. It works by `eval(...)` or by `compile(..)` this way:

```py
exec(compile('1<>0', 'foo', 'single', __future__.CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL))
```

```py
True
```

Comment: Great answer since it explains that this doesn't "work" in a normal script. But I'm not sure what is up with the last... sentence? The formatting and punctuation looks part joke, part carelessness, part vandalism. I just can't tell.

Comment: Oh, also, to clarify: even if you use `-i`, the script that is executed before you get to the REPL must follow normal Python 3 syntax, or you will get a syntax error. And if you get a syntax error in the script, then the REPL will behave as though you never did the import. (You just have to do it again at the REPL, but that defeats the point of putting it in your script in the first place.) It's OK if the script raises (most?) other kinds of exceptions though; the import will still be in effect when you get dumped to the REPL in that case.

Comment: Interesting, is it an expected behavior or just a bug because nobody really cares about this easter egg?

Comment: @AndreySemakin It is a perfect safe joke that looked like fake news about the future of Python. It can not break any script, even if someone would try to import all `__future__` features. (I removed a text that is no longer a part of this easter egg.)