# python: operator "<>" in conditional statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I am trying to understand some python code from the internet in which I found this line:

```
 if len(u) <> 2:
        # some statements
```

and:

```
  if idPlayer <> 0:
        # some statements
```

Tried to google it, nothing found, not even in the python documentation...

What does the conditional sign "<>" means?
When the conditions above are True?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007289/so-what-exactly-does-from-future-import-barry-as-flufl-do

Comment: I think it's the same of `!=`, but I have never seen it in python (I have seen that one in SQL before and it represent not equals)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm). This was the first link on google after searching: `<> in python`

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar: That doesn't come up at all when I perform that search. EDIT: no wait, it's buried further down the result list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an alternate version of !=, checking for non-equality.

Comment: Worth mentioning: it was removed from the language and doesn't work in python3.  Don't use it.

Comment: It goes way back to BASIC, by the way, and probably was adopted from there in Python's predecessor, ABC.